# Putting HTML code on JointJS link

Tags: javascript, html, jointjs

I have worked with JointJS now for a while, managing to create elements with HTML in them.

However, I am stuck with another problem, is it possible to place HTML code, like 
**href**, **img** etc, on a JointJS link and how do I do this?

For example, if I have this link, how do I modify it to contain HTML:

```
var link = new joint.dia.Link({
        source: { id: sourceId },
        target: { id: targetId },
        attrs: { 
            '.connection': { 'stroke-width': 3, stroke: '#000000' }
        }
    });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JointJS doesn't have a direct support for HTML in links. However, it is possible to do with a little bit of JointJS trickery:

```
// Update position of our HTML whenever source/target or vertices of our link change:
link.on('change:source change:target change:vertices', function() { updateHTMLPosition(link, $html) });
// Update position of our HTML whenever a position of an element in the graph changes:
graph.on('change:position', function() { updateHTMLPosition(link, $html) });

var $html = $('<ul><li>one</li><li>two</li></ul>');
$html.css({ position: 'absolute' }).appendTo(paper.el);

// Function for updating position of our HTML list.
function updateHTMLPosition(link, $html) {

    var linkView = paper.findViewByModel(link);
    var connectionEl = linkView.$('.connection')[0];
    var connectionLength = connectionEl.getTotalLength();
    // Position our HTML to the middle of the link.
    var position = connectionEl.getPointAtLength(connectionLength/2);
    $html.css({ left: position.x, top: position.y });
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dave! This solved the issue perfectly. I you have the time, please have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24384565/enabling-dragging-for-embedded-jointjs-elements-in-a-html-node) also related to JointJS.

Answer (score 3):

Bit of an old question, but thought I'd add some more ideas. You can add extra svg markup to the label in a link if you like by extending the link object and then setting attributes where needed. For example:

```
joint.shapes.custom.Link = joint.dia.Link.extend({
    labelMarkup: '<g class="label"><rect /><text /></g>'
});
```

This code overrides the markup for the label, so you can add extra elements in there. You can also update attributes on these elements by:

```
link.attr('text/text', "new text");
```

However hyperlinks won't work (at least I haven't got them working in Chrome) and I believe this is because Jointjs listens for all events in the model. So what you should do is use inbuilt events in Jointjs to listen for connection clicks:

```
paper.on('cell:pointerclick', function(cellView, evt, x, y){
    console.log(cellView);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip! However, I'm continually failing to add a custom tooltip to link labels. I added a <title /> attribute to the labelMarkup and tried to access it through cell.labels[0].attrs.title.text to no avail. It renders a tooltip if the SVG title element has an inline inner text (<title>Some Text</title>). Even adding the title element to the main link markup fails in the same manner. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?